# Transpositions and cycle graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, permutations

Recently I've stucked with the following problem.

Let $\Gamma$ be a cycle graph on $n$ vertices(vertices are basically numbers from $1$ to $n$). Consider the set of transpositions in $S_n$ which corresponds to the edges in $\Gamma$: edge from $a$ to $b$ is associated with transposition $(a \space b)$.

Prove that the product in $S_n$ of all such a transpositions can be decomposed into product of two disjoint cycles.

Well, since our graph is actually a cycle then within each transposition $(a \space b)$ in our set there also will be **exactly one** $(a \space c)$ and **exactly one** $(b \space d)$ for some $c \ne b$, $d \ne a$. Now we need to show that the product of all such a transpositions can be decomposed into two disjoint cycles. Any ideas?

Comment: You can show that the product of (12)(23)(34)...(n-1n)(n1) is (1)(234 ... n-1n) but it'll take a bit of work. So it is a cycle of length 1 and a cycle of length n-1

Comment: Well, basically, we may not have such a transpositions in a set

Comment: Or you mean that it doesn't matter since the product in both cases will have the same structure?

Comment: Yes that's right. I think you can assume without loss of generality that the cycle is the graph where $(i,i+1)$ is an edge for $i=1,...,n$ together with $(n,1)$. If it is not, then you will get a 1 cycle and and n-1 cycle as well, but where the fixed point and the n-1 cycle will be different. I'm actually not quite sure how to prove it.

Comment: By "product in $S_n$ of all such a transpositions" are you saying that it could be $(12)(23)...(n1)$ except that it might not be in the same order?

Comment: yes, I was talking about that